# unexpected Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I have a web application, which runs on JBoss web EAP 6.1.

It works fine, but sometimes at a certain point it logs this:

to be more precise when i ask a lot of times the connection it show me this error:

```
 Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException:Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss
```

Can you tell me what I should do about this?

[Here](http://pastie.org/8550139) you can find the full stacktrace of the error.

the connection is well configured. the probelm happen after 3 minutes of continuous query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most of the time it is because i must close the connection with the db sometime some connection are left open and jboss get crazy.

Answer (score 0):

From your log trace, it says: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/EmirDS

I suspect you didn't configure EmirDS as datasource at your JBoss. Here is how you can check using Jboss CLI, whether you have created it successfully!

1. From commandprompt, enter into JBOSS_HOME\bin
2. Type connect YOUR_IP:YOUR_PORT (example 192.169.1.10:9999)
3. Type this to see whether your datasource is available or not:

   /subsystem=datasources/data-source=EmirDS:test-connection-in-pool

You should see a msg like below if you are having a configured datasource named EmirDS

```
connection-in-pool
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [true]
}
```

Comment: no i m sorry it is not this. the connection is well configured. the probelm happen after 3 minutes of continuos query

Comment: As you are getting error after three minutes of continuous queries, then it can be the issue of number of allowable connections from your database ends. For example in PostgreSQL database by default you can have 100 connections at a time.

Comment: What should I put in YOUR_IP YOUR PORT?

Answer (score 0):

How to try this from command prompt

Type connect YOUR_IP:YOUR_PORT (example 192.169.1.10:9999)
Type this to see whether your datasource is available or not:

/subsystem=datasources/data-source=EmirDS:test-connection-in-pool